# PHP Session is lost on smartphones when returning to browser

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-variables, session-cookies

I have a checkout process that has the following stages:

1. Price Results
2. Customer Details
3. Payment
4. Order Confirmation

I use PHP session variables to store information along the way and I check these session variables exist throughout the buying process as the user proceeds with their purchase. I also have some code in place to stop users being able to hit the customer, payment or order confirmation page directly as this would mean they haven't obtained a quote on the results page and wouldn't have set the relevant session variables.

**The problem:**

It seems users who are getting quotes on tablets and smart phones are doing a lot of price comparison with other websites and leaving our site open in a tab. But the behaviour of such devices is different to desktop browsers.

It seems that if you leave a tab open and then go to another app, or load lots of other webpages, that when you try to return to a previous tab, the device will either:

- have the page loaded in the state you left it, OR
- will reload the tab URL as if it's a fresh hit to the page.

And there is the problem. If someone is on my customer page or payment page, and the URL gets a fresh hit, the session doesn't appear to exist and my code thinks someone is hitting the page for the first time, which throws a friendly error message to my customers saying to please restart their quote.

Is my system badly designed? Does anyone have any suggestions how I can get round this? I really need a way to allow customers to sit on a customer details stag or payment stage, maybe for a couple of hours and then be able to complete the buying process.

Should I be using sessions, cookies and database - or a combination?

Comment: Are you logging or processing anything to do with the customer's IP in your session handling? If you are then this may be the problem as the customer may be roaming between mobile data and wireless. Or the session may simply be expiring if they're having many pages open and coming back to your page much later on. You have two solutions: have your session expire much later on in time or you could use cookies to allow the browser to save their status, rather than rely on the server...

Comment: Increase the session timeout. That is the only way. Or make them close their open apps on the background. Which isn't the way to do it. But you can't do nothing about the refresh: only the user.

Comment: We set the session.gc_maxlifetime to 86400 as a test to see if 24 hours would be long enough. But we still get the loss of sessions and looking in the server variables I can see it's all mobile/tablet traffic. I realised this is due to how the browsers on devices like this operate. Reloading a URL after inactivity. I think I need to use a cookie or cookies here don't I. But if I was saving between 50-80 pieces of info session variables, is this still viable?

Comment: Can you restart an existing session if it's been lost? So if a user reloads the customer URL, can you save the session ID in a cookie, and reload the session back from that? I.e. does the server still have the information, just not the connection to the user? And this is where a cookie could help? I'm a tad confused here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can only be reliably solved by using cookies.
PHP can store its session variable in a cookie and read all relevant session parameters internally by the value the session cookie has.

So instead of an URL session you get a cookie session.

just use `session_start()` at the top of each of your PHP files or if you have a main object that always gets loaded first(for example `index.php`) place `session_start()` there.

Comment: I'm going to have a proper read of that this afternoon and get back to you on here with any questions if that's OK. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Hi Michael. So after more reading, the issue with tablets and phones is "tab discarding" - the OS will remove the tab cache and just store the URL, ready to reload the whole web page when you want it again. Now that seems to be killing my session as expected. But if I stored session_id() from the get-go in a cookie - can I not read this value when the page is loaded and start using that session, so the customer continues as if the session never ended? I did read that link above, but it's not clear if this is going to solve my issue just yet. Hope you can help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is stored in cookie, as per default with php it should upon page request request the cookie and reinitialise the the session. Are you sure you have your php configured to allow session cookies? Also, try to do a var_dump($_COOKIE); and see if the PHPSESSID cookie is present after you know it has been set(2nd page load with session active). To exclude browser just tossing all session data because session cookie will expire after browser determines session expires. To solve that you need to fiddle with session parameters or use a custom session cookie and session storage(database)

Comment: Hi Michael - are you available for a Skype IM or email at all? I'd love to show you our system but it's a bit sensitive to post on here. The PHP session cookie is definitely being set. I can see that using the var dump code you sent. It'd be really great to send you a few debug URL's just to get an opinion on what is going on?

Comment: if you do `void session_set_cookie_params ( int $lifetime [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]] )` before calling session start with lets say 15 minutes(15*60), does that resolve your issue? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php   by setting a fixed time you negate the session delete from the browser and force it to live for that amount of minutes.

Comment: Holy cow this appears to be working! Now is it ok to see this cookie to be 24 hours? Looking in our logs we see behaviour of customers using their tablets at home in the evenings, turning it on in the morning and trying to order - with the session broken. Is there any implication to setting lifetime to 86400 ? Really appreciate this help Michael.

Comment: It depends on how often you suspect to be hacked. The longer a session is the more effective a dictionary attack is. What i would advice is a popup after a leave of more that 15 minutes(with a lastseen var in sessionstorage) asking the customer to verify his identity by asking a personal detail like house number or last 3 digits of phone number. Make sure you emphasise that it is an identity protection feature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72175/discussion-between-james-wilson-and-michael-dibbets).